# Prevent a view from popping off in a NavigationView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI View that pushes a new detail view using a regular `NavigationLink`:

```
NavigationLink(destination: DetailView() ) { Text("Show Detail View")  }
```

I need a workaround to prevent the detail view from popping when the user presses the back button. I couldn't find a SwiftUI native way to do that.

Comment: That will be confusing for user, don't you want just hide back button with `navigationBarBackButtonHidden`? And that's it: no back button - no back navigation.

Comment: I need to display a message to the user in a specific case and prevent the pop, and in other cases i need the popping to work as is.

Comment: What about custom back button as leading navigation bar item? You'd have full control over action in there.

Comment: would you post this as an answer

Answer (score 4):

Please find below a possible approach using custom back button (note: adding any leading navigation bar item disables default back button automatically)

Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

```
struct DemoDetailsWithCustomBack: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var allowsBack = true

    var body: some View {
            Text("Details here")
                .navigationBarItems(
                    leading: Button(action: {
                        if self.allowsBack {
                            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        } else {
                            // activate alert here
                        }
                    }, label: { Image(systemName: "chevron.left") })
                )
    }
}

struct TestNavBarButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DemoDetailsWithCustomBack() ) { Text("Show Detail View")  }
        }
    }
}
```